# Javascript: insert input number value into closest number variable array onchange

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to insert a user input number value into the "41" var value=getClosestNum(**41**,intarray);.

I know "41" needs to be calling the name or the id from the input but my rusty Javascript attempts always seem to result with = 1. I've tried several getDocument, getID variants, sub functions, etc without success.

Ideally, the result would be instantaneous by using onChange on the input field without page reload.

Yes, it has to be JavaScript for incorporation later.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Find nearest value in javascript</title>
    <script language="javascript">
    // big array to come, example numbers
    var intarray=[1,2,3,5,7,9,11,33,40,42,44,55,66,77,88];
    // Now this function used to find out the close value in array for given number
    function getClosestNum(num, ar)
    {
        var i = 0, closest, closestDiff, currentDiff;
        if(ar.length)
        {
            closest = ar[0];
            for(i;i<ar.length;i++)
            {           
                closestDiff = Math.abs(num - closest);
                currentDiff = Math.abs(num - ar[i]);
                if(currentDiff < closestDiff)
                {
                    closest = ar[i];
                }
                closestDiff = null;
                currentDiff = null;
            }
            //returns first element that is closest to number
            return closest;
        }
        //no length
        return false;
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form>
            <input type="number" id="test" name="test" onChange="?">
        </form>

    <script language="javascript">
    document.write("Array: "+intarray+"<br>");
    document.write("Value to find 41 <br>");

    // CODE TO CHANGE "41" to id or named input
    // 41 to reference input field

    var value=getClosestNum(41,intarray);

    document.write("Response Received "+value);
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: call the function in the event's callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, you are trying to use the input element to take a number, and you would like to return the closest number to that input from the array.

I registered a function that fires on an 'input' event. Try this:

#### HTML

Add the following element to see the output of the function. You can redirect it later to wherever you need it.

`<p id="output"></p>`

#### JavaScript

```
// wrap in an onload function to ensure 
// that the elements exist before searching for them
window.onload = () => {
    
    // cache of elements on the page you want to use
    const testInputElement = document.getElementById('test');
    const outputElement = document.getElementById('output');
    
    // create a function that will fire whenever input is received
    testInputElement.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
        outputElement.innerHTML = getClosestNum(event.target.value, intarray);
    })
};
```

#### `onInput`  vs  `addEventListener('input')`

Adding `onInput` directly to the HTML inside an element is not as secure as registering a function programmatically via `addEventListener()`. If you have a function called, say, `handleInput()`, simply pass that name to addEventListener as an argument like so

`addEventListener('input', handleInput);`

## *Your code with the changes*

```
 <html>
<head>
<title>Find nearest value in javascript</title>
<script language="javascript">
// big array to come, example numbers
var intarray=[1,2,3,5,7,9,11,33,40,42,44,55,66,77,88];
// Now this function used to find out the close value in array for given number
function getClosestNum(num, ar)
{
    var i = 0, closest, closestDiff, currentDiff;
    if(ar.length)
    {
        closest = ar[0];
        for(i;i<ar.length;i++)
        {           
            closestDiff = Math.abs(num - closest);
            currentDiff = Math.abs(num - ar[i]);
            if(currentDiff < closestDiff)
            {
                closest = ar[i];
            }
            closestDiff = null;
            currentDiff = null;
        }
        //returns first element that is closest to number
        return closest;
    }
    //no length
    return false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <form>
        <input type="number" id="test" name="test" onChange="?">
    </form>
    <p id="output"></p>

<script language="javascript">
document.write("Array: "+intarray+"<br>");
document.write("Value to find 41 <br>");

// CODE TO CHANGE "41" to id or named input
// 41 to reference input field

var value=getClosestNum(41,intarray);

document.write("Response Received "+value);

// wrap in an onload function to ensure that the elements exist before searching for them
window.onload = () => {
    // cache of elements on the page you want to use
    const testInputElement = document.getElementById('test');
    const outputElement = document.getElementById('output');
    // create a function that will fire whenever input is received
    testInputElement.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
        outputElement.innerHTML = getClosestNum(event.target.value, intarray);
    })
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly. I really appreciate you providing the full html example so I can compare. Grateful.

Comment: If I wanted to change from only numbers to alphanumeric what would you suggest? I want to avoid a PHP solution to keep it client side with Javascript. An example of the data array set would be ae123 123456 ab ab124 234567 etc.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting rid of your reference to the `closestDiff` on every loop, you need to keep that value throughout the loop and update it when the diff decreases.

```
function getClosestNum(num, arr) {
    var closest;
    if (arr.length > 0) {
        closest = arr[0];
        var diff = Math.abs(arr[0] - num);
        for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            var currentDiff = Math.abs(arr[i] - num);
            if (diff > currentDiff) {
                closest = arr[i];
                diff = currentDiff;
            }
        }
    }
    return closest;
}
```